# Adding CSS to module_invoke() D7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How will I add a custom CSS to module_invoke() function in Drupal 7? I have superfish menu and I can get this to place to a right regions in my page that's why I'm planning to invoke it in my page and set a right css for this,

here's my code

```
     <nav id="customMenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <div id="navigation"><div class="section">
        <?php
            $block = module_invoke('superfish', 'block_view', '2');
            print render($block['content']);
        ?>
        </div></div> 
    </nav>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: use drupal_add_css() function before module_invoke()

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

1. By using '#attaching' property of element:

   $block['content']['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module_name') . '/css/my_module_name.css';
2. By using [drupal_add_css()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/77):

   drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module_name') . '/css/my_module_name.css');